# About bipartition and independent sets in graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-coloring

Suppose there's a bipartite graph. Then can I say that from the two bipartite partitions of V, the partition with max cardinality is the max independent set of that graph?

Since, all edges in a bipartite graph are cut edges (crossing b/w the two partitions), so there's no more edges to process, i.e. no more nodes to add to the max-cardinality partition without having both endpoints of an edge being in that same partition, which violates the property of independent sets.

If we can get the max independent set like so, then for a non-bipartite graph, can I 2-color the graph, and then from the two partitions, remove all bad edges (and their 2 endpoints) and call the remaining max-cardinality partition the max independent set of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for an arbitrary bipartite partition (that is, partition of the vertex set into two independent sets). E.g., a graph with two vertices and no edges could be divided into two singleton sets, but the max independent set has size 2, not 1.

Comment: I see, sorry, I've mentioned now in the question that I'm referring to the bipartite partition.

Comment: @PranjalVerma There can be more than 1 bipartite partition. Any partition into two independent sets is a bipartite partition.